# Call a function in an iFrame that is passed as string

Tags: javascript, function

What's the syntax to call a function in an iframe if the functionName is passed as string to a function?

```
function callIframeFunction(iframeID, functionName, args)
    //Gives Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    $("#"+iframeID)[0].contentWindow.document[functionName](args);       
}
```

I was also trying postMessage but without success:

```
var iframe = $('#iframeid')[0];
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('test', iframe.contentWindow.location);
```

Comment: Public global functions are usually on the `window` object and not the `document` object, depending of course on the function. You should implement [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) for this.

Comment: I tried postMessage but it doesn't seem to work (see updated post)

Comment: You need to receive and evaluate the messages as well. I advice to reread the link and check the given example.